# Get transformed xml on jenkins editable email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins newbie here.

There is this file say Books.xml and BookStyle.xsl in the workspace of a jenkins job. The xml uses the stylesheet xsl. If I open the Book.xml in firefox, I get the right styling.

Plan is to include the contents of the xml file with style within the [editable email](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) content in jenkins emails.

The default content text box of editable email is:

```
${FILE,path="versions.xml"}
```

And this doesn't show any styling in the emails being sent out.

How do we get the styling right in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to create the email with xml content and xsl styling.
Another way of achieving this requirement is to create a C# or java code to create an html file with the xml and xsl input. 
Call that script in build step to create an html file
Then use that html file in editable email content box.

convert.cs

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

class myclass
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
// Load the style sheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("header.xsl");

// Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
xslt.Transform("versions.xml", "report.html");
}

}
```

Build steps
    ***csc convert.cs
    convert.exe***

Editable email content box
    ***${FILE,path="report.html"}***

Comment: This may not be the direct answer to what I was looking for, but in the absence of other suggestions I will select this as answer. May change it later if we get another answer. Thanks Angel.